# How to let Makefile see target from another file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have such `Makefile` with a content for creating a script:

```
.PHONY cluster-run 
cluster-run:
        make $(TARGET) --just-print >> tmp_script.sh;
```

And another one `nn.mk`:

```
.PHONY nn-model
include Makefile

nn-model:
    python run-nn.py
```

I have two separate Makefiles for readability, because their content is big and I have another '*.mk' files, like `nn-lstm.mk`, `nn-conv.mk`, etc.

I launch as follows:

```
make -f nn.mk cluster-run TARGET=nn-model
```

But `make` gives an error:

```
make nn-model --just-print >> tmp_script.sh;
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `nn-model'.  Stop.
make: *** [cluster-run] Error 2
```

For me such behaviour is strange because target `nn-model` actually exists. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should never use raw `make` in recipes.  Always use the `$(MAKE)` variable.

Second, the problem is because when you run the sub-make you don't provide the `-f` option:

```
make nn-model --just-print >> tmp_script.sh;
```

Because of that, it reads `Makefile` but not `nn.mk`, and so there's no rule to build the target `nn-model`.

Remember if you run a sub-make like this it's starting an entirely new make process with a clean slate: none of the targets defined in the parent make process are known to the sub-make when it starts.

I don't know what you mean by *target `nn_model` actually exists* but there's definitely no file named `nn_model` or you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: How can I get a path passed with `-f` argument to a parent process?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question, but there's no way for the child make to interrogate the parent make to find out what it was using.  You have to modify the parent make's recipe that invokes the child make, so that it passes the correct options.  Really, I think that your makefile organization is problematic and you should do something different.  I think this may be an XY problem: if you described more clearly what problem you're trying to solve by having your makefiles structured this way perhaps we could suggest better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

So what's happening is that when you build `cluster-run` it invokes a recursive make, which reads `Makefile`, and asks it to build   `$(TARGET)` (which will include `nn-model`).

Notice that the recursive make is a new make and does not inherit variables or rules from the parent make, so this make instance has no clue how to build `nn-model`   If you want the child make to see this, then the child make must include the parent one...